# Show that the equality is true

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If $f$ is a Completely multiplicative function and $g$ is an arithmetic function such as $g(1) \neq 0$ prove that:

$$(f\cdot g)^{-1} = f\cdot g^{-1}$$

Any function with the -1 as exponent is the Dirichlet Inverse.

My try:

Applying the Dirichlet inverse definition to the LSH we have:

$$ \Large (f\cdot g)^{-1}(n) = \frac{-1}{(f\cdot g)(1)} \sum_{d|n \atop d<n}(f\cdot g)\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)\cdot (f\cdot g)^{-1}(d) \quad $$

Is there any definition that can help me to separate them?

Comment: But $\cdot$ is not the Dirichlet convolution, but simple multiplication?

Comment: Im not sure!! But i guess is simple product because in classes we use * for Dirichlet convolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recursive formula for the Dirichlet inverse is just going to complicate matters. It's best to approach these things directly:

To show $f.g^{-1}$ is $(f.g)^{-1}$, you have to prove $ (f.g^{-1})*(f.g) = e$, where $e(1)=1$ and $e(n)=0$ for $n>1$. So let's calculate:

$$ ((f.g^{-1})*(f.g))(n) = \sum_{d|n} (f.g^{-1})(d).(f.g)(n/d)$$
$$=\sum_{d|n}f(d)g^{-1}(d)f(n/d)g(n/d).$$

Now use the fact that $f$ is completely multiplicative to collect the $f$ terms appearing inside the sum and factor them outside. Then use the fact that $g*g^{-1}=e$ to show the result is 0 for $n>1$ and for $n=1$ equal to $f(1)$. Now show $f(1)=1$ and you're done.

Comment: Understood.. but why you affirm that $(f \cdot g^{-1})(d) = f(d)\cdot g^{-1}(d)$

Comment: This is the definition, isn't it? $(f.g)(n) = f(n).g(n)$, with $.$ denoting ordinary multiplication, for any functions $f$, $g$.

Comment: Yes, its true!!! Thank you!! i´m practicing for my Number theory test....